# masking view не работает на android >= 21

Tags: android, view, bitmap, mask

Делаю прогрессбар. Он не одноцветный, а градиентный, поэтому добавление layout в layout не прокатит, надо чтобы градиент не расширялся на прогрессе, а открывался. Пошарил по просторам и соорудил такое решение

```
public class LineProgressBar extends FrameLayout {

    Bitmap maskBitmap;
    Paint p;
    Paint q;
    PorterDuffXfermode porterDuffXfermode;

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int progressMaskWidth;


    public LineProgressBar(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public LineProgressBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.line_progress_bar_height);
        width = Decorator.screenWidthPix;
        progressMaskWidth = width;
        if (getLayoutParams() == null) {
            setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(width, height));
        } else {
            getLayoutParams().height = height;
            getLayoutParams().width = width;
        }

        p = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        p.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        q = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

        porterDuffXfermode = new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN);

        invalidateBitmap();

        setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        setBackground(new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.LEFT_RIGHT,
                new int[]{0xff3bffb7, 0xff1ce9ff, 0xffcc9dfc}));
    }

    private void invalidateBitmap() {
        maskBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(progressMaskWidth, this.height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        invalidate();
    }

//    public void setAlignedView(View view){
//        if (view.getLayoutParams() != null && view.getLayoutParams().width > 0) {
//            width = view.getLayoutParams().width;
//            progressMaskWidth = width;
//            invalidate();
//        }
//    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        q.setXfermode(porterDuffXfermode);
        canvas.drawBitmap(maskBitmap, width - progressMaskWidth, 0, q);
        q.setXfermode(null);
    }

    public void setProgress(int percent) {
        if (percent < 100) {
            progressMaskWidth = (int) ((100 - percent) * ((double) width / 100));
        } else {
            progressMaskWidth = 1;
        }
        invalidateBitmap();
    }
}
```

При установке прогресса мы вычисляем ширину маски, а в ondraw мы помещаем ее в конец view. На пре-lollipop все работает прекрасно, однако на 21+ версии андроид маска получается не прозрачной, а черной. Как можно обработать такой кейс? Поддерживаю API до 16го включительно, и не хотелось бы от этого уходить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А чем вас стандартный прогресс бар не устраивает? Назначаете ему вот такой pgogressDrawable и не надо никаких своих виджетов писать...

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff3bffb7"
                android:centerColor="#ff1ce9ff"
                android:endColor="#ffcc9dfc" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Как пишут на en-so - best answer ever . Большое спасибо